# SQL Query Last value of child table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables where primary key is uniqueidentifier and there are not dates inside of them. One table has info where is stored and has relationship to another table which is tracking status, each status is new row for history purpose. Now the problem is taking last row from second table and status.

Table 1

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | uniqueidentifier |
| BoxNum | nvarchar(25) |

Table 2

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Id | uniqueidentifier |
| status | int |
| Table1_FK_ID | uniqueidentifier |

Status has the following meaning:

0 for new
10 - approved
20 - rejected
30 - blocked

Each box can be rejected than approved or opposite.
So my question is how I can get last inserted record in table2, something like this:

Result

| BoxNum | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 444444 | 10 |
| 444445 | 20 |
| 444412 | 30 |

Comment: (Standard) SQL is not designed for tracking historical changes of data. If you need such information you need to add means to find it yourself – if you have an auto-incremening id you might just look for the maximum (provided there are not that many data sets that overflow might occur) or you add an explicit timestamp.

Comment: SELECT ... FROM ParentTable OUTRE APPLY (SELECT TOP(1) ... FROM ChildTable WHERE ? ORDER BY DESC) x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If uniqueidentifier is sequential you can also use subquery like that;

```
SELECT 
   T1.BoxNum,
   (SELECT TOP 1 T2.Status 
      FROM [Table 2] T2 
         WHERE T2.Table1_FK_ID = T1.Id ORDER BY T2.Id DESC) AS Status
FROM [Table 1] T1
```

But if there is no related data in second table it could be error, then you need to check data existence.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing this is simplified example of your data. Basically, you need a column on which to order the status records in the second table.

If your `uniqueidentifier` is [SEQUENTIAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) the solution will be:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES T1.[BoxName]
                      ,T2.[Status]
FROM [Table 1] T1
INNER JOIN [Table 2] T2
    ON T1.[Id] = T2.[Table1_FK_ID]
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.[Id] ORDER BY T2.[ID] DESC);
```

but if it is not you need to add record_id or date_add columns in order to know which record is the last one inserted.

Comment: Unfortunately is not working when you have mixed statuses added. Example(0,10,10,30,10) Doesn't give the latest, gives me 30 instead of 10.That is main problem, I do not have date columns and to add now doesn't have sense 3 years of data will not have dates ...

Comment: If there is no way to deterministically order the inserted data, there is no way to solve your issue.